# Finding the highest version in my list of lists

Tags: python, list, filtering, ironpython

I have a list of lists:

```
['test', 'testlink', 1]
['test', 'testlink', 2]
['test ', 'testlink', 3]
['test ', 'testlink', 4]
['test 2', 'test2link', 1]
['test 2', 'test2link', 2]
['test 3', 'test3link', 1]
['test 3', 'test3link', 3]
['test 3', 'test3link', 4]
```

I want to filter the list to return the maximum for the 3rd element for each unique 1st element.

The result I want is:

```
['test ', 'testlink', 4]
['test 2', 'test2link', 2]
['test 3', 'test3link', 4]
```

I am struggling to find a way to do this. The code block below gets to my sorted list of lists but I'm stuck after that.

```
#create some dummy data
rows=[]
rows.append(["test","testlink",1])
rows.append(["test 2","test2link",1])
rows.append(["test 3","test3link",1])
rows.append(["test","testlink",2])
rows.append(["test","testlink",1])
rows.append(["test 2","test2link",1])
rows.append(["test 3","test3link",1])
rows.append(["test ","testlink",3])
rows.append(["test 3","test3link",3])
rows.append(["test ","testlink",4])
rows.append(["test 3","test3link",4])
rows.append(["test 2","test2link",2])
#filter out duplicates
newRows = []
for elem in rows:
    if elem not in newRows:
        newRows.append(elem)
rows = newRows
#sort the lists
rows = sorted(rows,key=lambda x: (x[0],x[2]))
```

Thanks all sorted both the answers given can be made to work in my Ironpython environment

Comment: do you not care about the second element at all? what happens if two lists have the same first element, but different second elements?

Comment: if they have same first element and different third element they have by default a different 2nd element. Sorry my dummy code didn't exemplify that. :-). The important element is 3rd element as that is the current version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution using `itertools.groupby` ([doc](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby)):

```
rows=[]
rows.append(["test","testlink",1])
rows.append(["test 2","test2link",1])
rows.append(["test 3","test3link",1])
rows.append(["test","testlink",2])
rows.append(["test","testlink",1])
rows.append(["test 2","test2link",1])
rows.append(["test 3","test3link",1])
rows.append(["test ","testlink",3])
rows.append(["test 3","test3link",3])
rows.append(["test ","testlink",4])
rows.append(["test 3","test3link",4])
rows.append(["test 2","test2link",2])

from itertools import groupby

out = []
for v, g in groupby(sorted(rows, key=lambda k: k[0].strip()), lambda k: k[0].strip()):
    item = max(g, key=lambda k: k[2])
    out.append(item)

from pprint import pprint
pprint(out)
```

Prints:

```
[['test ', 'testlink', 4],
 ['test 2', 'test2link', 2],
 ['test 3', 'test3link', 4]]
```

Comment: Thanks for this I did wonder of the answer lay in itertools. I need to check if it's available to me in the Ironpython environment the production code needs to end up in.

Comment: @PoorGolfer Looking at https://documentation.help/IronPython/itertools.html#itertools.groupby `groupby` should be there

Comment: Yes it is available. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict):

```
from collections import defaultdict

l = [['test', 'testlink', 1],
     ['test', 'testlink', 2],
     ['test', 'testlink', 3],
     ['test', 'testlink', 4],
     ['test 2', 'test2link', 1],
     ['test 2', 'test2link', 2],
     ['test 3', 'test3link', 1],
     ['test 3', 'test3link', 3],
     ['test 3', 'test3link', 4]]

d = defaultdict(int)
for first, second, third in l:
    if d[(first, second)] < third:
       d[(first, second)] = third
```

To form result in format you want use next line:

```
res = [[*key, value] for key, value in d.items()]
```

---

If you don't want to import `defaultdict` you can use regular one:

```
d = {}
for first, second, third in l:
    item = d.get((first, second), None)
    if not item or item < third:
       d[(first, second)] = third
```

Comment: Thank you. I get the idea, but that doesn't quite do what I want as the returned results are in the form  [(first,second), third] . I think the res=[[*key.... the * is a typo as i get a syntax error when it's included. removing the * gets the results but with the first two bracketed as shown.

Comment: `*` isn't  typo, it's [unpacking](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#tut-unpacking-arguments) ;)

Comment: @PoorGolfer, I've validated code before posting an answer, it works as expected. Could you provide error occured?

Comment: I think it's a limitation of my python environment. I am using ironpython which is based on python 2.7.  I believe *key is Python 3 only. Thanks again.

Comment: @PoorGolfer, for python2 use `res = [[key[0], key[1], value] for key, value in d.items()]`

Comment: @PoorGolfer, you can select my answer in case if it helpful for you.